# Can i save the opencv_traincascade results?

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, cmd

When training a detector with OpenCV in cmd are displayed some tables as above

```
 +-----+----------+-----------+
 |  N  |    HR    |     FA    |
 +-----+----------+-----------+
```

and also the acceptanceRatio for each stage. These values are note stored in the .xml file. Is there a possibility to save those values somewhere? I need them if i let the computer over the night to train and cmd does not save more than a certain number of lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the standard output to a file when invoking the tool. For instance, `opencv_traincascade all_your_parameters > output.txt` will write everything to 'output.txt'.